# Sending graphQL requests by chunks in Nestjs

Tags: axios, graphql, request, nestjs

I'm sending this query to graphql, the main part is "deviceIds: result" which is an array with objects… I want to send this array by chunks if it's more then 20 items long… so if there are 100 objects I want to send this request 5 times with 20 objects in the array…

Is it possible to do with axios.all?

```
await axios({
url: `${process.env.HOST}/graphql`,
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            query: `
         query goes here
            variables: {
                deviceIds: result,
            },
        },
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.data) { 
               res.data =res.data.data && res.data;
            }
            graphqlData = res.data;
            if(!graphqlData){graphqlData=[]}
        })  .catch((err) => {
            throw new HttpException(err.response, 400);
        });
```

Comment: ... promise.all

Comment: Thanks, question is, is it ok if I map over "result" array….in the map function I return axios call…. this then store the returned data from map in in the variable …. and then await Promise.all(variable) ?